# Bulk inserting a csv in SQL using a formatfile with 1 entry for multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

I am trying to import data from csv which has 7 columns into a View with 8 columns.

Here is my FMT;

```
14.0
8
1       SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      1     PaymentUniqueNumber                        SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2       SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      2     RequestDate                                SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR             0       200     ","      3     Amount                                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR             0       200     ","      4     Currency                                   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
4       SQLCHAR             0       200     ","      5     TransactionType                            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
5       SQLCHAR             0       1000    ","      6     TransactionStatus                          SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
6       SQLCHAR             0       1000    ","      7     ExtractStatus                              SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
7       SQLCHAR             0       2000    "\r\n"   8     ReversalStatus                             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Note that 3rd entry is repeated for 2 columns. Basically the Amount format is **10.00 USD** and during insertion, I want it to be divided into Amount and Currency Column.

This is what I have tried so far. Here is my select query

```
SELECT
    RowSource.PaymentUniqueNumber,
    RowSource.RequestDate,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(RowSource.Amount,0,CHARINDEX(' ',RowSource.Amount,0)))) AS Amount,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(RowSource.Amount,CHARINDEX(' ',RowSource.Amount,0)+1,LEN(RowSource.Amount)))) As Currency,
    --RowSource.Amount,
    --RowSource.Currency,
    RowSource.TransactionType,
    RowSource.TransactionStatus,
    RowSource.ExtractStatus,
    RowSource.ReversalStatus
    FROM OPENROWSET
    (BULK 'C:\test.csv', 
    FORMATFILE = 'C:\test.fmt',
    CODEPAGE = 'RAW',
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    MAXERRORS = 0,
    ROWS_PER_BATCH = 0
) AS RowSource;
```

View:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ReportsVW]
AS
SELECT        PaymentUniqueNumber, RequestDate, Amount, Currency, TransactionType, TransactionStatus, ExtractStatus, ReversalStatus
FROM            dbo.Reports
GO
```

And Sample data is:

```
Payment Unique Number,Request Date,Amount,Transaction Type,Transaction Status,Extract Status,Reversal Status
2654947309179233378,26/06/2021 23:59:01,13.00 QAR,Pay,2994 - Payment method selected,To be confirmed ,Reversal not required
1051819298326286815,26/06/2021 23:58:22,580.00 QAR,Pay,0000 - Payment Processed Successfully,Confirmation Acknowledged,Reversal not required
```

For this particular attempt, I am receiving

**Cannot bulk load. Invalid column number in the format file in C:\test.fmt**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/non-xml-format-files-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) say the Format-file field contains "A number that indicates the position of each field in the data file. The first field in the row is 1, and so on."  Seems to suggest it must be unique

Comment: What about making the numbering unique, and making the separator after `Amount` a space `" "`

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please edit your question and add the following: (1) sample of input *.csv file, (2) DDL for SQL Server target table, i.e. `CREATE TABLE ...`

Comment: @booota . . . My advice is to load the data into a staging table where all the columns are strings.  Then do the data manipulation as a SQL query.

Comment: #2 is still missing: 'CREATE TABLE dbo.Reports ...`. We need to know that table structure and columns data types.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to achieve my target, Comments will be appreciated;

```
14.0
7
1       SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      1     PaymentUniqueNumber                        SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2       SQLCHAR             0       50      ","      2     RequestDate                                SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR             0       41      ","      3     Amount                                     ""
4       SQLCHAR             0       200     ","      5     TransactionType                            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
5       SQLCHAR             0       1000    ","      6     TransactionStatus                          SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
6       SQLCHAR             0       1000    ","      7     ExtractStatus                              SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
7       SQLCHAR             0       2000    "\r\n"   8     ReversalStatus                             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

and the query

```
SELECT
    RowSource.PaymentUniqueNumber,
    Convert(smalldatetime,RowSource.RequestDate,103) AS RequestDate,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(RowSource.Amount,0,CHARINDEX(' ',RowSource.Amount,0)))) AS Amount,
    LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(RowSource.Amount,CHARINDEX(' ',RowSource.Amount,0)+1,LEN(RowSource.Amount)))) As Currency,
    RowSource.TransactionType,
    RowSource.TransactionStatus,
    RowSource.ExtractStatus,
    RowSource.ReversalStatus
    FROM OPENROWSET
    (BULK 'C:\test1.csv', 
FORMATFILE = 'C:\test1.fmt',
CODEPAGE = 'RAW',
FIRSTROW = 2,
MAXERRORS = 0,
ROWS_PER_BATCH = 0
) AS RowSource;
```

1. Skipped the currency column in fmt
2. manipulated the Currency column in select query

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

I modified format file as XML. IMHO, the XML format is better:

- It is structured.
- It has two sections: one for a csv file, 2nd for a db table

And the SQL is much simpler as it calculates a space position in the Amount just once.

**Input 'e:\Temp\Boota.csv' file**

```
Payment Unique Number,Request Date,Amount,Transaction Type,Transaction Status,Extract Status,Reversal Status
2654947309179233378,26/06/2021 23:59:01,13.00 QAR,Pay,2994 - Payment method selected,To be confirmed ,Reversal not required
1051819298326286815,26/06/2021 23:58:22,580.00 QAR,Pay,0000 - Payment Processed Successfully,Confirmation Acknowledged,Reversal not required
```

**Format 'e:\Temp\Boota.xml' file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <RECORD>
        <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' MAX_LENGTH="20"/>
        <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' MAX_LENGTH="20"/>
        <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' MAX_LENGTH="20"/>
        <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' MAX_LENGTH="20"/>
        <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' MAX_LENGTH="100"/>
        <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=',' MAX_LENGTH="100"/>
        <FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='\r\n' MAX_LENGTH="100"/>
    </RECORD>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="PaymentUniqueNumber" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="RequestDate" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="Amount" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="TransactionType" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="TransactionStatus" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="ExtractStatus" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="ReversalStatus" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
    </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

**SQL**

```
;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK 'e:\Temp\Boota.csv'
        , FORMATFILE = 'e:\Temp\Boota.xml'  
        , ERRORFILE = 'e:\Temp\Boota.err'
        , FIRSTROW = 2 -- real data starts on the 2nd row
        , MAXERRORS = 100
    ) AS tbl
)
SELECT PaymentUniqueNumber, RequestDate
    , Amount = LEFT(Amount, pos - 1), Currency = RIGHT(Amount, LEN(Amount) - pos)
    , TransactionType, TransactionStatus, ExtractStatus, ReversalStatus 
FROM rs
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CHARINDEX(SPACE(1), Amount))) AS t(pos);
```

**Output**

```
+---------------------+---------------------+---------+----------+-----------------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+
| PaymentUniqueNumber |     RequestDate     | Amount  | Currency | TransactionType |           TransactionStatus           |       ExtractStatus       |    ReversalStatus     |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------+----------+-----------------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+
| 2654947309179233378 | 26/06/2021 23:59:01 |  13.00  | QAR      | Pay             | 2994 - Payment method selected        | To be confirmed           | Reversal not required |
| 1051819298326286815 | 26/06/2021 23:58:22 | 580.00  | QAR      | Pay             | 0000 - Payment Processed Successfully | Confirmation Acknowledged | Reversal not required |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------+----------+-----------------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------+
```